# recursion relation problem solve only using back substitution method

Tags: recursion, computer-science

here  the question is -
T(n) = T(n/2) + nlogn  for n>1
=  1 for n=1

solve this by using back subtitution methord only.

I can't able to solve this .

if the question is follows i can slove with ease :
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + nlogn  for n>1
=  1 for n=1
but for the upper equation i can't able to solve .

Comment: Are you looking for a precise value or for "order of magnitude".  What if n isn't a power of 2?